# Unity IAP not initializing

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, app-store

I used the Unity "Purchaser script"(In Unity's IAP example) to test IAP's but they do not initialize on the phone during testing even though they do initialize and pass in the editor. I understand the Unity Editor always passes IAPs so that means I did not do a step somewhere on the Apple side. iTunes connect states that IAPs must be submitted with the app update so I do not see how I could individually create the IAP on iTunes Connect for testing. Can someone please help me understand where I go from here to be able to initialize and use the IAPs? All help is extremely appreciated.

NOTE: this is an update to an app which DOES NOT contain IAPs. Also, I have made SURE that my Product ID matched the one in my script.

Summary:

1. IAPs work in unity editor, not on iPhone
2. I created the IAP on itunes connect and it has a matching Product ID as the one in my script, which is the Unity-provided "Purchaser Script"
   (Shown here: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/analytics/integrating-unity-iap-your-game)
3. Error is on initialization of the purchase, it is failing.

Purchaser code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Purchasing;

// Placing the Purchaser class in the CompleteProject namespace allows it to interact with ScoreManager, one of the existing Survival Shooter scripts.
//namespace CompleteProject
//{

// Deriving the Purchaser class from IStoreListener enables it to receive messages from Unity Purchasing.
public class Purchaser : MonoBehaviour, IStoreListener
{

    private static IStoreController m_StoreController;                                                                    // Reference to the Purchasing system.
    private static IExtensionProvider m_StoreExtensionProvider;                                                         // Reference to store-specific Purchasing subsystems.

    // Product identifiers for all products capable of being purchased: "convenience" general identifiers for use with Purchasing, and their store-specific identifier counterparts 
    // for use with and outside of Unity Purchasing. Define store-specific identifiers also on each platform's publisher dashboard (iTunes Connect, Google Play Developer Console, etc.)

private static string kProductIDConsumable = "RyanCbuy100G";
private static string kProductIDConsumable2 =    "RyanCbuy200G";                                                         // General handle for the consumable product.
private static string kProductIDConsumable3 =    "RyanCbuy300G";    
private static string kProductIDConsumable4 =    "RyanCbuy400G";


private static string kProductNameAppleConsumable =    "RyanCbuy100G";             // Apple App Store identifier for the consumable product.
private static string kProductNameAppleConsumable2 =    "RyanCbuy200G";             // Apple App Store identifier for the consumable product.
private static string kProductNameAppleConsumable3 =    "RyanCbuy300G";     
private static string kProductNameAppleConsumable4 =    "RyanCbuy400G"; 




    void Start()
    {
        // If we haven't set up the Unity Purchasing reference
        if (m_StoreController == null)
        {
            // Begin to configure our connection to Purchasing
            InitializePurchasing();
        }
    }

    public void InitializePurchasing() 
    {
        // If we have already connected to Purchasing ...
        if (IsInitialized())
        {
            // ... we are done here.
            return;
        }

        // Create a builder, first passing in a suite of Unity provided stores.
        var builder = ConfigurationBuilder.Instance(StandardPurchasingModule.Instance());

        // Add a product to sell / restore by way of its identifier, associating the general identifier with its store-specific identifiers.
        builder.AddProduct(kProductIDConsumable, ProductType.Consumable, new IDs(){{ kProductNameAppleConsumable,       AppleAppStore.Name },});// Continue adding the non-consumable product.
        builder.AddProduct(kProductIDConsumable2, ProductType.Consumable, new IDs(){{ kProductNameAppleConsumable2,       AppleAppStore.Name },});// Continue adding the non-consumable product.
        builder.AddProduct(kProductIDConsumable3, ProductType.Consumable, new IDs(){{ kProductNameAppleConsumable3,       AppleAppStore.Name },});// Continue adding the non-consumable product.
        builder.AddProduct(kProductIDConsumable4, ProductType.Consumable, new IDs(){{ kProductNameAppleConsumable4,       AppleAppStore.Name },});// Continue adding the non-consumable product.
        // Kick off the remainder of the set-up with an asynchrounous call, passing the configuration and this class' instance. Expect a response either in OnInitialized or OnInitializeFailed.
        UnityPurchasing.Initialize(this, builder);
    }


    private bool IsInitialized()
    {
        // Only say we are initialized if both the Purchasing references are set.
        return m_StoreController != null && m_StoreExtensionProvider != null;
    }


    public void BuyConsumable()
    {
        // Buy the consumable product using its general identifier. Expect a response either through ProcessPurchase or OnPurchaseFailed asynchronously.
        BuyProductID(kProductIDConsumable);
    }

public void BuyConsumable2()
{
    // Buy the consumable product using its general identifier. Expect a response either through ProcessPurchase or OnPurchaseFailed asynchronously.
    BuyProductID(kProductIDConsumable2);
}

public void BuyConsumable3()
{
    // Buy the consumable product using its general identifier. Expect a response either through ProcessPurchase or OnPurchaseFailed asynchronously.
    BuyProductID(kProductIDConsumable3);
}
public void BuyConsumable4()
{
    // Buy the consumable product using its general identifier. Expect a response either through ProcessPurchase or OnPurchaseFailed asynchronously.
    BuyProductID(kProductIDConsumable4);
}




    void BuyProductID(string productId)
    {
        // If the stores throw an unexpected exception, use try..catch to protect my logic here.
        try
        {
            // If Purchasing has been initialized ...
            if (IsInitialized())
            {
                // ... look up the Product reference with the general product identifier and the Purchasing system's products collection.
                Product product = m_StoreController.products.WithID(productId);

                // If the look up found a product for this device's store and that product is ready to be sold ... 
                if (product != null && product.availableToPurchase)
                {
                    Debug.Log (string.Format("Purchasing product asychronously: '{0}'", product.definition.id));// ... buy the product. Expect a response either through ProcessPurchase or OnPurchaseFailed asynchronously.
                    m_StoreController.InitiatePurchase(product);
                }
                // Otherwise ...
                else
                {
                    // ... report the product look-up failure situation  
                    Debug.Log ("BuyProductID: FAIL. Not purchasing product, either is not found or is not available for purchase");
                }
            }
            // Otherwise ...
            else
            {
                // ... report the fact Purchasing has not succeeded initializing yet. Consider waiting longer or retrying initiailization.
                Debug.Log("BuyProductID FAIL. Not initialized.");
            }
        }
        // Complete the unexpected exception handling ...
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // ... by reporting any unexpected exception for later diagnosis.
            Debug.Log ("BuyProductID: FAIL. Exception during purchase. " + e);
        }
    }


    // Restore purchases previously made by this customer. Some platforms automatically restore purchases. Apple currently requires explicit purchase restoration for IAP.
    public void RestorePurchases()
    {
        // If Purchasing has not yet been set up ...
        if (!IsInitialized())
        {
            // ... report the situation and stop restoring. Consider either waiting longer, or retrying initialization.
            Debug.Log("RestorePurchases FAIL. Not initialized.");
            return;
        }

        // If we are running on an Apple device ... 
        if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer || 
            Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.OSXPlayer)
        {
            // ... begin restoring purchases
            Debug.Log("RestorePurchases started ...");

            // Fetch the Apple store-specific subsystem.
            var apple = m_StoreExtensionProvider.GetExtension<IAppleExtensions>();
            // Begin the asynchronous process of restoring purchases. Expect a confirmation response in the Action<bool> below, and ProcessPurchase if there are previously purchased products to restore.
            apple.RestoreTransactions((result) => {
                // The first phase of restoration. If no more responses are received on ProcessPurchase then no purchases are available to be restored.
                Debug.Log("RestorePurchases continuing: " + result + ". If no further messages, no purchases available to restore.");
            });
        }
        // Otherwise ...
        else
        {
            // We are not running on an Apple device. No work is necessary to restore purchases.
            Debug.Log("RestorePurchases FAIL. Not supported on this platform. Current = " + Application.platform);
        }
    }


    //  
    // --- IStoreListener
    //

    public void OnInitialized(IStoreController controller, IExtensionProvider extensions)
    {
        // Purchasing has succeeded initializing. Collect our Purchasing references.
        Debug.Log("OnInitialized: PASS");

        // Overall Purchasing system, configured with products for this application.
        m_StoreController = controller;
        // Store specific subsystem, for accessing device-specific store features.
        m_StoreExtensionProvider = extensions;
    }


    public void OnInitializeFailed(InitializationFailureReason error)
    {
        // Purchasing set-up has not succeeded. Check error for reason. Consider sharing this reason with the user.
        Debug.Log("OnInitializeFailed InitializationFailureReason:" + error);
    }


    public PurchaseProcessingResult ProcessPurchase(PurchaseEventArgs args) 
    {
        // A consumable product has been purchased by this user.
        if (String.Equals(args.purchasedProduct.definition.id, kProductIDConsumable, StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            Debug.Log(string.Format("ProcessPurchase: PASS. Product: '{0}'", args.purchasedProduct.definition.id));//If the consumable item has been successfully purchased, add 100 coins to the player's in-game score.
        inpMoveH i = new inpMoveH();
        i.addGold (50);
        //UpdateGoldScript updater = new UpdateGoldScript ();
        //updater.updateGold ();
        }

        // Or ... a non-consumable product has been purchased by this user.
        else if (String.Equals(args.purchasedProduct.definition.id, kProductIDConsumable2, StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            Debug.Log(string.Format("ProcessPurchase: PASS. Product: '{0}'", args.purchasedProduct.definition.id));
        inpMoveH i = new inpMoveH();
        i.addGold (100);
    }// Or ... a subscription product has been purchased by this user.
    else if (String.Equals(args.purchasedProduct.definition.id, kProductIDConsumable3, StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        Debug.Log(string.Format("ProcessPurchase: PASS. Product: '{0}'", args.purchasedProduct.definition.id));
        inpMoveH i = new inpMoveH();
        i.addGold (250);
    }
    else if (String.Equals(args.purchasedProduct.definition.id, kProductIDConsumable4, StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        Debug.Log(string.Format("ProcessPurchase: PASS. Product: '{0}'", args.purchasedProduct.definition.id));
        inpMoveH i = new inpMoveH();
        i.addGold (1000);
    }
        // Or ... an unknown product has been purchased by this user. Fill in additional products here.
        else 
        {
            Debug.Log(string.Format("ProcessPurchase: FAIL. Unrecognized product: '{0}'", args.purchasedProduct.definition.id));}// Return a flag indicating wither this product has completely been received, or if the application needs to be reminded of this purchase at next app launch. Is useful when saving purchased products to the cloud, and when that save is delayed.
        return PurchaseProcessingResult.Complete;
    }


    public void OnPurchaseFailed(Product product, PurchaseFailureReason failureReason)
    {
        // A product purchase attempt did not succeed. Check failureReason for more detail. Consider sharing this reason with the user.
        Debug.Log(string.Format("OnPurchaseFailed: FAIL. Product: '{0}', PurchaseFailureReason: {1}",product.definition.storeSpecificId, failureReason));}
}
```

XCODE ERROR:

```
m_StoreController IS NULL.

 Purchaser:IsInitialized()
 Purchaser:InitializePurchasing()

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)

m_StoreControllerProvider IS NULL.

Purchaser:IsInitialized()
Purchaser:InitializePurchasing()

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)

ReturningFalse
Purchaser:IsInitialized()
Purchaser:InitializePurchasing()

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)

2016-06-12 11:56:32.106 RC1[254:9485] UnityIAP:Requesting 4 products
2016-06-12 11:56:32.118 RC1[254:9485] UnityIAP:Requesting product data...
2016-06-12 11:56:32.866 RC1[254:9485] UnityIAP:Received 0 products
2016-06-12 11:56:32.870 RC1[254:9485] UnityIAP:No App Receipt found
Unavailable product RCbuy100Gold -RCbuy100Gold
UnityEngine.Purchasing.PurchasingManager:CheckForInitialization()
UnityEngine.Purchasing.PurchasingManager:OnProductsRetrieved(List`1)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.AppleStoreImpl:OnProductsRetrieved(String)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.AppleStoreImpl:ProcessMessage(String, String,  String, String)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.Extension.UnityUtil:Update()

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)

Unavailable product RCbuy250Gold -RCbuy250Gold
UnityEngine.Purchasing.PurchasingManager:CheckForInitialization()
UnityEngine.Purchasing.PurchasingManager:OnProductsRetrieved(List`1)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.AppleStoreImpl:OnProductsRetrieved(String)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.AppleStoreImpl:ProcessMessage(String, String, String, String)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.Extension.UnityUtil:Update()

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)

Unavailable product RCbuy650Gold -RCbuy650Gold
UnityEngine.Purchasing.PurchasingManager:CheckForInitialization()
UnityEngine.Purchasing.PurchasingManager:OnProductsRetrieved(List`1)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.AppleStoreImpl:OnProductsRetrieved(String)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.AppleStoreImpl:ProcessMessage(String, String, String, String)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.Extension.UnityUtil:Update()

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)

Unavailable product RCbuy1000Gold -RCbuy1000Gold
UnityEngine.Purchasing.PurchasingManager:CheckForInitialization()
UnityEngine.Purchasing.PurchasingManager:OnProductsRetrieved(List`1)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.AppleStoreImpl:OnProductsRetrieved(String)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.AppleStoreImpl:ProcessMessage(String, String, String, String)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.Extension.UnityUtil:Update()

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)

OnInitializeFailed InitializationFailureReason:NoProductsAvailable
Purchaser:OnInitializeFailed(InitializationFailureReason)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.PurchasingManager:CheckForInitialization()
UnityEngine.Purchasing.PurchasingManager:OnProductsRetrieved(List`1)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.AppleStoreImpl:OnProductsRetrieved(String)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.AppleStoreImpl:ProcessMessage(String, String, String, String)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.Extension.UnityUtil:Update()

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/ UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)

2016-06-12 11:56:32.887 RC1[254:9485] UnityIAP:addTransactionObserver
m_StoreController IS NULL.

Purchaser:IsInitialized()
Purchaser:BuyProductID(String)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCallList:Invoke(Object[])
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
    UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchPress(PointerEventData, Boolean, Boolean)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchEvents()
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:Process()

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)

m_StoreControllerProvider IS NULL.

Purchaser:IsInitialized()
Purchaser:BuyProductID(String)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCallList:Invoke(Object[])
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
   UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchPress(PointerEve ntData, Boolean, Boolean)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchEvents()
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:Process()

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/  UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)

ReturningFalse
Purchaser:IsInitialized()
Purchaser:BuyProductID(String)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCallList:Invoke(Object[])                UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
   UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchPress(PointerEventData, Boolean, Boolean)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchEvents()
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:Process()

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/ UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)

BuyProductID FAIL. Not initialized.
Purchaser:BuyProductID(String)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCallList:Invoke(Object[])
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject,     BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
  UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchPress(PointerEventData, Boolean, Boolean)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchEvents()
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:Process()
```

Comment: I've had a look at the sample code in the URL you provided... can you post the code that is using the `Purchaser` object? For example - it looks like `void BuyProductID(string productId)` is failing because `IsInitialized()` is `false`... have you called `public void InitializePurchasing()`? Have you stepped through that call? That method also calls `IsInitialized()` - does it return `true` in the call to `InitializePurchasing()`?

Comment: Please check it out @GavinHope

Comment: I really appreciate you looking into this btw

Comment: opening the scene calls the script to begin (with onStart() ) and clicking the button for the purchase calls one of the buyComsumable methods. Every variable that is not consumable1, consumable2, consumable3, or consumable4 is not needed but I did not want to mess with things too much so I left them in there.

Comment: @GavinHope please post your solution as an answer so, if you fix it, I can give you the bounty

Comment: Can I just check: (1) you only have a single IAP set up in iTunesConnect and (2) you only have the IAP set up in Apple's iTunesConnect and nothing for the Google Play Store?

Comment: @GavinHope I have made sure that (1) All the IAPs are added to iTunes connect and (2) all of these IAPs are for the Apple App Store. I updated my code to make it more legible.

Comment: @Ryan did you fix the problem? I have added a product (status is Ready to Submit) and it is not initializing too. UnityIAP:Received 0 products

Comment: @MaxTyT I did fix the problem. The issue is that I was not testing through Testflight. When I tested through Testflight vs just compiling onto my phone was the difference between it working and not. Please make sure to set up a sandbox account first in iTunes connect. You will have to put in credit card info to set up the apple account, but it is not charged because it uses fake money. If this does not help, tell me and ill try to help more

Comment: @Ryan I've put my app to Internal Testing. Do I need to use the TestFlight app? If yes then I can't because it requires iOS 8.0 (I have Iphone 4). I can only compile. Could you please add me on Skype? Maxtyt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that you would already solve the issue. If not I am going to share some screenshots of how I did it on the Apple Developer page:

1- Upload an app to testflight (upload an app to the console using XCode or application loader) - This step is already completed.

2- Go to Features [image: Features] and add as many items as you want. I believe that you have items here with "submit for revision" status. As you can see I have it approved and working in my unity project. [image: approved]

3- The IAP items should be active for testing after 24h (for your testflight approved users). To add users you have to go to [Apple Developer Console](https://developer.apple.com/) and edit the roles in there for the provisioning profile.

4- If you did all that (which I believe you did); the only thing that is left is the XCode side. However, I am going to recommend you to add your IAP script in the scene as an empty object to make sure that it is initialized and you give it enough time to set everything properly.

5- XCODE: To add IAP functionality you need to set the proper permissions in your provisioning profile and add the capabilities [image: XCODE].

6 - Further help with the team provisioning: provides with some useful help. [Apple IAP Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html) -> Xcode will update your certificate if you check the IAP function.

Anyway, I had the same issue as you are having, my Google IAP was working but my iOS build was failing the purchase process. My final advise is to review all the code/settings/certificates and wait 24h to be sure that Apple applied the changes to your app.

Let us know please.

Thanks.

Comment: It had never worked up until I tested it on TestFlight, you solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: I gave you the bounty @Cabrra

Comment: Sometimes Apple can be a little tricky with the requirements. However you can always rely on this community. Glad to help you.

Comment: your help is very much appreciated, you have no idea. thank you.

Comment: @Cabrra hi, I uploaded my app to TestFlight. Do I have to install it from AppStore or can I just build and run it on my device? Because I have iPhone 4 I can't install TestFlight app. Also my items have status "Ready to Submit". IAP is not working :(

Answer (score 8):

I was receiving "Received 0 products" until I filled in Contact Info, Bank Info and Tax Info. I was so mad I couldn't make it work for more then 2 month.

Answer (score 4):

So, in your code, there's a call to `Start()` that calls `InitializePurchasing()` which then sets up the `ConfigurationBuilder` and ultimately calls:

```
UnityPurchasing.Initialize(this, builder);
```

I think you're setting up the builder with things that you don't need, specifically the **GooglePlay** product IDs. E.g. from your `InitializePurchasing()` method:

```
// Add a product to sell / restore by way of its identifier, associating the general identifier with its store-specific identifiers.
builder.AddProduct(kProductIDConsumable, ProductType.Consumable, new IDs(){{ kProductNameAppleConsumable, AppleAppStore.Name },{ kProductNameGooglePlayConsumable,  GooglePlay.Name },});// Continue adding the non-consumable product.
builder.AddProduct(kProductIDConsumable2, ProductType.Consumable, new IDs(){{ kProductNameAppleConsumable2, AppleAppStore.Name },{ kProductNameGooglePlayConsumable,  GooglePlay.Name },});// Continue adding the non-consumable product.
builder.AddProduct(kProductIDConsumable3, ProductType.Consumable, new IDs(){{ kProductNameAppleConsumable3, AppleAppStore.Name },{ kProductNameGooglePlayConsumable,  GooglePlay.Name },});// Continue adding the non-consumable product.
builder.AddProduct(kProductIDConsumable4, ProductType.Consumable, new IDs(){{ kProductNameAppleConsumable4, AppleAppStore.Name },{ kProductNameGooglePlayConsumable,  GooglePlay.Name },});// Continue adding the non-consumable product.
UnityPurchasing.Initialize(this, builder);
```

**I would start** by calling `AddProduct` with just the details for a single store (the iOS App Store). *(I'd also remove all the code that you don't need, the additional consumable products, as it's just clogging up your code with things you don't need, making it harder to work out what's going on)_.

For example, from one of the [Unity 3d pages](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Purchasing.ConfigurationBuilder.AddProduct.html):

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Purchasing;

public class MyStoreClass : MonoBehaviour, IStoreListener {
    void Start() {
        ConfigurationBuilder builder = ConfigurationBuilder.Instance(StandardPurchasingModule.Instance());
        builder.AddProduct("levelpackfoo", ProductType.NonConsumable, new IDs() { "levelpackfoo", AppleAppStore.Name });
        UnityPurchasing.Initialize(this,builder);
    }
    public void OnInitialized(IStoreController controller, IExtensionProvider extensions) {}
    public void OnInitializeFailed(InitializationFailureReason error) {}
    public PurchaseProcessingResult ProcessPurchase(PurchaseEventArgs e) { return PurchaseProcessingResult.Complete; }
    public void OnPurchaseFailed(Product item, PurchaseFailureReason r) {}
}
```

In that example code, the've got the `ConfigurationBuilder` being created, added-to, and initialised all in the `Start()` method...

**Even before doing that**, however, you should be able to find out the result of your call to: `UnityPurchasing.Initialize(this, builder);`...

I would do this because, the failure you're getting is:

```
"BuyProductID FAIL. Not initialized."
```

So, we know that the call to `if (IsInitialized())` in `void BuyProductID(string productId)` is returning false, leading to:

```
else
{
    // ... report the fact Purchasing has not succeeded initializing yet. Consider waiting longer or retrying initiailization.
    Debug.Log("BuyProductID FAIL. Not initialized.");
}
```

And here's the `IsInitialized()` method:

```
private bool IsInitialized()
{
    // Only say we are initialized if both the Purchasing references are set.
    return m_StoreController != null && m_StoreExtensionProvider != null;
}
```

So, one of `m_StoreController` or `m_StoreExtensionProvider` is null... Now let's look at the two `IStoreListener` callbacks:

```
//  
// --- IStoreListener
//

public void OnInitialized(IStoreController controller, IExtensionProvider extensions)
{
    // Purchasing has succeeded initializing. Collect our Purchasing references.
    Debug.Log("OnInitialized: PASS");

    // Overall Purchasing system, configured with products for this application.
    m_StoreController = controller;
    // Store specific subsystem, for accessing device-specific store features.
    m_StoreExtensionProvider = extensions;
}

public void OnInitializeFailed(InitializationFailureReason error)
{
    // Purchasing set-up has not succeeded. Check error for reason. Consider sharing this reason with the user.
    Debug.Log("OnInitializeFailed InitializationFailureReason:" + error);
}
```

Check your debug logs (or put a breakpoint in each of those methods)... after the earlier call to `UnityPurchasing.Initialize(this, builder);` - which are you getting?

- `OnInitialized`?
- `OnInitializeFailed`?

You need to know if you're getting `OnInitialized` success and therefore initialising `m_StoreController` and `m_StoreController`.

#### Update 1

Not sure if you've consulted these pages from the Unity docs; the first has a walkthrough of the IAP setup for iTunesConnect and your Xcode project and the second provides additional info:

- [Unity: Configuring for Apple App Store](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityIAPAppleConfiguration.html).
- [Unity: Store Guide, iOS and Mac App Stores](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityIAPiOSMAS.html).

Comment: @GavingHope I used the Log to find out that m_StoreController and m_StoreControllerProvider are both NULL

Comment: ERROR: "OnInitializeFailed InitializationFailureReason:NoProductsAvailable "  . The first message it gives me is that m_StoreController is null. Then It says that it calls to the store for products and the store does not return anything

Comment: I am noticing a main issue here is that it is not recieving the products. I will include the whole error message above

Comment: I've got some more questions:
(1) This is an existing app that's in the store? And *currently* does not have IAPs?
(2) You've created an IAP in iTunesConnect - how many? One or four?
(3) Have you created a new version for the app, for the update that will have the IAP(s)?
(4) Are they consumable IAP in iTunesConnect?
(5) Is "RyanCbuy100G" the Product ID or the Reference Name?

Comment: I've also update the answer with an additional link to the unity docs, incase you haven't read that page...

Comment: this is an existing app that does not use IAPs, I created all four IAPs but I have not put them into an update. They are on iTunes Connect as Consumables and "RyanCbuy100G" is the Product ID.

Comment: And trust me, I have read all the pages you can find about Unity IAPs published by Unity

Comment: Have you created a new version for the app itself, in iTunesConnect? Obviously not submitted yet, but created a new version, that I believe is what the IAPs you have created will be associated with...

Comment: I just did that. Would that have prevented it from working? @GavinHope

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114567/discussion-between-gavin-hope-and-ryan).

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you created an IAP product on Itune connect and product Id is matched between code and itune connect and bundle Id is correct:

Maybe you hasn't select the **Team** in project setting. You'll also need to create a sandbox tester account and log out real appstore account on testing device for fully test IAP

Comment: This did not fix the problem unfortunately

Comment: If stil not fixed you can also consider using MobiShop https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/63636 - ( it hasnt got support for Unity's IAP SDK and interacts directly with the native iOS/Android billing )

Answer (score 1):

Since this was my first IOS in app purchase setup the item blocking me was filling out the tax and bank info. Once that was done I was able to test with a sandbox account.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem. After that I try to apply it on "itunes connect" on the contract for `paid applications` (contact info, tax info, bank info) 
try this direct link
https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/da/jumpTo?page=contracts

Answer (score 0):

If the settings in IAP Unity are correct, the purchase on the editor is successful.
Then all you have to do is check this section, the banking information, tax and "Paid Apps" section in Agreements is enabled.
Like the picture below
[image]