# Can the 'StandardPurchasingModule' be used for Unity In App Purchases?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I've been looking at the Unity Engine / Unity 3d documentation to help out with this question: [Unity IAP not initializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37737619/unity-iap-not-initializing/37773303#37773303).

I'm using a separate question (here) rather than trying to tease out the information via *comments* - in hope of discovering more so that an answer to *that* question can be advanced...

I've seen the following in the [sample code](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Purchasing.UnityPurchasing.Initialize.html), to *Initialize Unity IAP with the specified listener and configuration*:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Purchasing;

public class MyStoreClass : MonoBehaviour, IStoreListener {
    void Start() {
        var module = StandardPurchasingModule.Instance();
        ConfigurationBuilder builder = ConfigurationBuilder.Instance(module);
        builder.AddProduct("levelpackfoo", ProductType.NonConsumable);
        UnityPurchasing.Initialize(this, builder);
    }
    public void OnInitialized(IStoreController controller, IExtensionProvider extensions) {}
    public void OnInitializeFailed(InitializationFailureReason error) {}
    public PurchaseProcessingResult ProcessPurchase(PurchaseEventArgs e) { return PurchaseProcessingResult.Complete; }
    public void OnPurchaseFailed(Product item, PurchaseFailureReason r) {}
}
```

What I can't find out about is the `StandardPurchasingModule` class, and the static method `Instance()`...

Is this just a placeholder in the docs/api for something that needs to be implemented? Or, does it provide default implementations for the likes of the Apple App Store?

For example, [Implementing a Store](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityIAPImplementingAStore.html) suggests that and implementation for `IStore` must be provided.

More to the point, an implementation of `IPurchasingModule` would return an `IStore`... and it's an `IPurchasingModule` that is needed as a parameter to the static, [ConfigurationBuilder.Instance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Purchasing.ConfigurationBuilder.Instance.html):

```
public static Purchasing.ConfigurationBuilder Instance(Purchasing.Extension.IPurchasingModule first, params IPurchasingModule[] rest);
```

Can `StandardPurchasingModule.Instance()` be used? Or is it necessary to provide implementations for this suite of store and purchasing interfaces?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Yes, you can use it. Just check that your version of Unity supports the store you need.

The documentation for StandardPurchasingModule is almost non-existent. But if you look at the [Unity tutorial for implementing IAP](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/ads-analytics/integrating-unity-iap-your-game) and read the comments in the provided Purchaser script, you'll see the following comment about the StandardPurchasingModule:

// Create a builder, **first passing in a suite of Unity provided stores**.

The implication being that StandardPurchasingModule is an implementation of [IPurchasingModule](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Purchasing.Extension.IPurchasingModule.html) that implements functionality for the stores your version of Unity supports. So yes, you should be able to use it as long as your version of Unity supports the store you need.