# Send the latest version of Itunesconnect to review

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, app-store-connect

The first version I sent to iTunesConnect 1.1 (6)

> "IOS 11.4 on Wi-Fi is connected to an IPv6 network.
>
> Specifically, no action occurs when you try to purchase your in-app
>   purchase products. "

it was rejected with justification.

I then modified the sections I thought I was primarily writing in the Unity IAP section and sent it to Build and Xcode. I saved it in Xcode with version number 1.2 (7), saved it in the archive section, and then sent it to the iTunnesConnect with validate and upload.

If you click on the "Submit for review" button after you click on "Save" button after you see the latest version in it's Add Build section, you will again send 1.1un (6) version to iTunnesConnect.

This happened twice and was rejected twice.

Is there something wrong with me?

How do I submit the latest version for review?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your current version is rejected, you should remove the build and select a new build in the `build` section. 
[image]

> I saved it in Xcode with version number `1.2 (7)`, saved it in the
>   archive section, and then sent it to the iTunnesConnect with validate
>   and upload.

I assume you are building `1.2` but not `1.1`. Because in your case you should see a the new build (7) when you try to add a new build and save.

If you are releasing `1.1`, stick to build version `1.1` but increase the build number.

Comment: As far as I understand, I have to apply with a new version 1.1 (7).
Did I get right?

Comment: Yes. Have a try.

Comment: I will immediately go to the Mac and apply for review again by first making unity and then making changes in xcode.

Comment: I sent it for review. I'm waiting for the reply to the review. I will share the result here.thank you for your interest

Comment: Good to know :) !

Comment: I am sorry for being late.
Just as you said, you can change the build (X) number and send it to "V1.1 (7)".
Thank you very much for your interest.

but it was rejected again.
I think this is my problem right now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47469014/9909066